# How to read list with "Insert-only" permission [SharePoint 2010 in C#]

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I'm using SharePoint 2010 and making webparts in C#.

I have a list where "Domain Users" can only insert entries to a list. The reason behind it is that we don't want any user to see what's in this list. Sort of a list for tickets requests.

Now, I need to make a webpart that displays entries submitted by the logged in user. If I am to make the webpart normally, I'd have to give the user read-permission. Now that I can't, I'm clueless.

Any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx)

Anyway why you don't give the read permissions for only the item submitted by the current user ?

Comment: do what ? `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` or Read Permission ? For `RnWithElevatedPrivileges` see the link of the answer for read permissions you can: 1. Create a workflow (with designer) 2. Create a Event Handler 3. List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Item-Level Permission

Comment: I think I'll stick to RunWithElevatedPrivileges. It suits our environment better *COUGH*IDON'TKNOWHOWTOWORKAROUNDWORKFLOWS*COUGH*.